# Estimating the number of streets in $CITY?

Tags: estimation, algorithms

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask these kinds of questions.
I want to estimate the number of streets there are in a certain city. Any advice? How would you begin?

(To be precise, I want to calculate the number of streets of [Valladolid](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Valladolid/@41.6411899,-4.7324666,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xd47728c08c66e93:0xb3ff92d41ca26bef), but I suppose that in order to calculate it I must have into consideration things like: area, maybe population or density ... so the calculation can be extrapolable depending on some variables, at least in part).

Comment: Look at the index of a city streetmap

Comment: Oh, good one. I didn't think about it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd buy a street directory, turn to the index, and (if it's just too many to count the entries) measure the number of column-inches (/cm) of streets listed. Then I'd subtract the distance taken up by any headings, whitespace or other entries that don't constitute a new street. Then I'd count how many streets are listed in say 4 inches (or 10cm). Then I'd multiply by the total column inches to get an estimated count. Then I'd check for any double counting (say where streets are listed twice). Or, I'd try phoning the city administration, since they might already know the number.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "street." Would you count a contiguous set of polylines with the same street name as a single street or as multiple streets? What about if these polylines abruptly change direction?  What about if they are not quite connected but otherwise continue in the same direction? Would you count a two-way street twice--one for each direction--and one-way streets only once? Would you count a continuous road running in the same direction as one street even if its name changes along the way? What if nothing changes except the postal code?

Comment: My definition of street would be "A street that can be searched using Google Maps".

Comment: That's clearer , but it's not an effective definition (because we cannot download the Google maps database for a city, so it still begs the question of how to determine when two streets should be considered the same or different). More importantly, this might have little to do with most practical questions about streets in a city. Perhaps you could tell us *why* you want to estimate the number of streets?

Comment: It's just curiosity. I've read about job interviews asking similar questions.

Comment: Maybe the point of such interview questions is to see whether the interviewee is thinking about these basic issues of *problem definition* :-).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could have a precise estimation of the number of streets in an historical city (like Valladolid) with a regression (if you will not use a lot of variables). Personally, I would use a more ICT approach, writing a script to look into a website, such as http://www.paginasamarillas.es/, for the addresses associates to the stored public numbers. I will delete all the duplicates, and I will count the items inside the array to have an estimate.

Comment: How would you identify duplicates? Many cities contain different streets with the same name and streets that look the same on the map but have different names. What exactly do you mean by estimate the number "with a regression"?

Comment: 1) You will identify duplicates by their names. In that way you won't only get streets with the same name and streets where no one has registered a telephone number. 2) I mean that, if you have cross-sectional datas regarding the number of the streets, population, economics datas, etc. of other cities, you will hardly get a precise estimation of the number of the streets in Valladolid. You should have quite similar datas for quite similar cities, but I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: As I pointed out, names do not usually determine duplicates: any city of a moderate size will have distinct streets with the same name. Using telephone numbers assures you will only count a subset of streets: for instance, many main highways might not have any registered addresses; no limited-access highway will show up that way. Whether these biases in your recommendation are important in any circumstance will depend on the application, but it's important to understand they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at Google maps and make an estimate. Choose a small region of medium street density and count the streets. Then estimate the numbers of those regions within the city boundary. That should get you an estimate to about 30% accuracy. I'd say there are about 1200 just from glancing at the google map in your link. How accurate do you need it?